# R losing a column when writing to csv

Tags: r, stock-data

I download some stock data from yahoo. When I save this as a csv the first column (containing the dates) is lost. Any thoughts?

```
library (tidyverse)
library(forecast)
ftse <- getSymbols('^FTSE', auto.assign=FALSE, from = '2013-01-01', src= 'yahoo')
na.fill(ftse, "extend")
ftse_df <- as.data.frame (ftse)
ftse_df
colnames(ftse_df)<- c("open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adjusted")
ftse_df
write_csv(ftse_df,"C:/Users/xxx/ftse.csv")
```

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: can you please `dput(head(ftse_df))` so we can see the format of the data frame?  Post it into your original question as an edit.

Comment: The dates are stored as row names rather than a column. `write.csv` will include them in your file, but I think `write_csv` omits them

Comment: Using write.csv did the trick - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you press Ctrl+Enter to visualise "ftse_df" do you see the first column?
If not, there should be a problem above.

If you see the correct dataset, you can try this:

```
write_csv(ftse_df,"C:/Users/xxx/ftse.csv", row.names= TRUE)
```

Hope it will work!

Cheers,
Beatrice

Answer (score 0):

Using write.csv solves this - opening the csv file shows the date column in place.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert to data.frame or to write out the entire path.  Use `write.zoo` and `~` like this where it is assumed that on your system `path.expand("~")` is
`"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents"`

```
library(quantmod)

ftse <- getSymbols('^FTSE', auto.assign=FALSE, from = '2013-01-01')
write.zoo(ftse, "~/../ftse.csv", quote = FALSE, sep = ",",
  col.names = c("date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adjusted"))
```

Check the file

```
readLines("~/../ftse.csv", n = 3)
## [1] "date,open,high,low,close,volume,adjusted"                                                               
## [2] "2013-01-02,5897.7998046875,6044.60009765625,5897.7998046875,6027.39990234375,652659400,6027.39990234375"
## [3] "2013-01-03,6027.39990234375,6051.2998046875,6016.7998046875,6047.2998046875,470665900,6047.2998046875"
```

Comment: If I use this method the date isn't carried over and an index (1,2,...) appears instead.  May I ask how this method differs from setting up a data frame?

Comment: I have shown the file output so you can can see that that is not so.  Seems like no point in converting it to some other form when it serves no purpose.  If you do have some use for a data frame convert it using `fortify.zoo`